# D3 chord diagram with many values

Tags: d3.js, chord-diagram

I am new to d3 was trying to make a chord diagram.

But I am able to make it with four arrays only, how can I make it for 10? I was going through another example for d3 but I was still not able to understand it.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.chord path {
  fill-opacity: .67;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

// From http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/circos/guide/tables/
var matrix = [
  [11975,  5871, 8916, 2868],
  [ 1951, 10048, 2060, 6171],
  [ 8010, 16145, 8090, 8045],
  [ 1013,   990,  940, 6907]
];

var chord = d3.layout.chord()
    .padding(.05)
    .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
    .matrix(matrix);

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    innerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * .41,
    outerRadius = innerRadius * 1.1;

var fill = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(4))
    .range(["#000000", "#FFDD89", "#957244", "#F26223"]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(chord.groups)
  .enter().append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.index); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return fill(d.index); })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius))
    .on("mouseover", fade(.1))
    .on("mouseout", fade(1));

var ticks = svg.append("g").selectAll("g")
    .data(chord.groups)
  .enter().append("g").selectAll("g")
    .data(groupTicks)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"
          + "translate(" + outerRadius + ",0)";
    });

ticks.append("line")
    .attr("x1", 1)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 5)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .style("stroke", "#000");

ticks.append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)translate(-16)" : null; })
    .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.label; });

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "chord")
  .selectAll("path")
    .data(chord.chords)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.chord().radius(innerRadius))
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.target.index); })
    .style("opacity", 1);

// Returns an array of tick angles and labels, given a group.
function groupTicks(d) {
  var k = (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / d.value;
  return d3.range(0, d.value, 1000).map(function(v, i) {
    return {
      angle: v * k + d.startAngle,
      label: i % 5 ? null : v / 1000 + "k"
    };
  });
}

// Returns an event handler for fading a given chord group.
function fade(opacity) {
  return function(g, i) {
    svg.selectAll(".chord path")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.source.index != i && d.target.index != i; })
      .transition()
        .style("opacity", opacity);
  };
}

</script>`
```

Can you explain how does the map function work?

Answer (score 3):

The matrix you specify needs to be a square matrix to designate the flow between elements. That is, each array must be as long as there are arrays. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/7992932) is an example with a 10x10 matrix.

Comment: Thanks. I realised it after asking the question. Its working :)